# ClickOnce Installation Url on several servers

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

My WPF application should be deployed to several servers and each server should have his own ClickOnce Installation Url. Is there any way or any software to modify each Installation Url automatically?

Comment: Is mage a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the installation URL by using command:
"YourApplicationPath\setup.exe" /url="YourInstallationUrl/"

The mage.exe will help you to change the providerUrl